# Primavera V10, Extensibilidade, CustomTab na "Ficha de Artigo", como detectar e delegar função quando o próprio CustomTab é escolhido?

Tags: c#

Primavera V10, Extensibilidade, `CustomTab`, tenho um `CustomTab` criado na "Ficha de Artigo", como detectar quando o o `CustomTab` é seleccionado e atribuir uma funcção?

Quando pesquiso nos exemplos, só encontro para o próprio `CustomTab`:

```
this.Loading += new Primavera.Extensibility.Patterns.CustomTab.EventDelegate(this.PricesMargins_Loading);
this.Saving += new Primavera.Extensibility.Patterns.CustomTab.EventDelegate(this.PricesMargins_Saving);
```

Comment: Não percebi o que pretende @José. O que pretende é executar algo quando o `CustomTab` é acionado?

Comment: @jose não existe um activate disponível.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizei a função  `this.VisibleChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.checkTab);` para detectar quando o CustomTab fica visivel ou não.